# How to make TextField which has 2 hintText?

Tags: flutter, dart, uitextfield, textfield, textformfield

I have ui of text field from Figma.

There are 2 hint texts where 1st hintText is located at the beginning of textfield and other one is at the end.

[image: Here is ui]

As can be seen, trailing is hint text which is disappearing when user inputs number.

If you have any idea please share how to make this kind of text field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), child: Text('Prefix')),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: "Cym",
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the trailing for the hint and can you onChanged method to handle changes.. Like you will be managing your text on the behavior of input. For example if the input is empty then you text will be something like "A" if you input something text will be changed.

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffix: Text(text)
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  // handle or change your text here
                  if(value.isEmpty){
                    setState(() { text = "A"});
                  }
                  else{
                    setState(() { myState = "any text"});
                  }
                },
              )
```